# How to update a value in finish method of Database.Batchable

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

I am implementing a callout in Database.batchable

```
public with sharing class BatchDocusignStatus implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts 
{
    public Temp_REST_Auth__c auth {get;set;}
    public List<Map<String, String>> appStatus = new List<Map<String, String>>();

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) 
    {         

        String query = 'SELECT Id, Envelope_ID__c, Application__c FROM DocusignHistory__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);        


    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sobject> scope) {



        String ApplicationId = '';
        String DocusignStatus = '';


        List<DocusignHistory__c> histories = (List<DocusignHistory__c>) scope;


        for(DocusignHistory__c history : histories) 
        {
            DocusignStatus  = getStatus(history.Envelope_ID__c); 
            ApplicationId = history.Application__c;

            Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>();
            m.put(ApplicationId, DocusignStatus);

            appStatus.add(m);
        } 

    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) 
    {

        String app;
        String status;

        for(Integer i = 0; i<appStatus.size(); i++ )
        {
            System.Debug('==> appStatus' + appStatus[i]);
            for (String s : appStatus[i].keySet())
            {
                app = s;
                status = appStatus[i].get(s);
            }

            UpdateApplication(app, status);                
        }

    }

    public void UpdateApplication(String appId, String docusignStatus)
    {
        Application__c app;
        List<Application__c> apps = [SELECT Id, Docusign_Status__c FROM Application__c WHERE Id=:appId];
        if(apps.size() > 0)
        {
            app = apps[0];
            app.Docusign_Status__c = docusignStatus;

            System.Debug('Inside UpdateApplication. App is ' + app);

            update app;
        }        
    }

    public String getStatus(String envelopeId)
    {
        // DocusignRestUtilDemo.authData = auth;
        Docusign_Access_Token__c accessToken = DocusignRestUtilDemo.getAccessToken(); 

        // System.Debug('authData is ' + auth);
        String endpoint = DocusignRestUtilDemo.authData.RequestEnvelopeEndpoint__c + DocusignRestUtilDemo.authData.DSAccountID__c + '/envelopes/' + envelopeId;            


        // initialize the api client for the desired environment
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');

        //set Authentication Header
        request.setHeader('grant_type', 'Bearer');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken.Token_Value__c);
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

        // request.setBody(JSON.serialize(statusUpdate));

        HttpResponse response = h.send(request);

        String responseStatus = response.getStatus();
        System.Debug('responseStatus' + responseStatus);

        DocusignRestUtilDemo.EnvelopeCreationResponse resp = (DocusignRestUtilDemo.EnvelopeCreationResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), DocusignRestUtilDemo.EnvelopeCreationResponse.class);

        return resp.status;   
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is, in `finish` method, I want to perform an update operation in an object.

There, I found that, the `appStatus` variable is not set in `finish` method.

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Variables modified during the execute method are not saved between calls to execute or finish by default. You need to include the Database.Stateful interface to indicate that you wish to persist changes to these variables between executions.

```
public with sharing class BatchDocusignStatus 
  implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful
```

You can read more about this [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.